# Encryption Used against Utf Strings

Tags: tel

Can anyone tell me what kind of encryption this is?

Using nodeJS to detect the encoding gives me "Utf 8 :" but cannot decode it to readable string.

```
if(_0x474dx11[_0x1004[54]]== true
```

Comment: Maybe adding some more background would help. Also the if statement looks invalid

Comment: Okay the code encryption is mixed with utf 8,which is easily by JS "utf8.decode("\x43\x6F\x6E\x74\x65\x6E\x74\x2D\x54\x79\x70\x65")   but not  "_0x474dxd"     Here is the Partial Code:     var _0x474dxe=CryptoJS[_0x1004[48]][_0x1004[47]](_0x474dxd,_0x474dx8[_0x1004[45]],{iv:_0x474dx8[_0x1004[46]]});var _0x474dxf=_0x474dxe[_0x1004[50]].toString(CryptoJS[_0x1004[49]].Base64);var _0x474dx10=_0x1004[51];var _0x474dx11={data:_0x474dxf};var _0x474dx12={headers:{"\x43\x6F\x6E\x74\x65\x6E\x74\x2D\x54\x79\x70\x65":_0x1004[53]}};